# slow full-text-search in MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have table with +800k records with simple schema (just `id` [int] and full text index on `note` [text]). Every time I insert new record I use php script to strip all strings shorter than 4 chars and all stop words. Than the processed string is inserted in DB. When I search for some common keyword it takes +4s to get result and whole DB is stuck during the search. What am I doing wrong?

//edited
schema:

```
id int(11) NOT NULL,
text mediumtext COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FULLTEXT KEY text (text)
```

query:

```
SELECT table_name.id FROM table_name WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ("+keyword" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Could you add queries to your question?

Comment: Can we see the schema and what query is slow? (Aside: presumably you mean words *shorter* than 4 chars?)

Comment: I've added schema and query (Aside: yes, sorry for that :) )

Comment: The 4 secs time is just the query time or php time to retrieve the values?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing

```
WHERE note LIKE '%keyword%'
```

?

Because if you are, I'm not surprised it's slow.

You have two choices. Either break it into individual works, and store each word by itself in the database, along with an ID, and then link that ID to the note_id.

Or, read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html and add an index of type FULLTEXT to your database.

Comment: I've already had fulltext index and I use query with "match against"

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM fulltext search is known to be quite inefficient [1] when dealing with large datasets. InnoDBs fulltext search in MySQL 5.6 will maybe be the solution but now your best possibility is to use external fulltext engines like Sphinx or Lucene/Solr if you can install new software on the server.

[1] http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/files/presentations/EuroOSCON2006-High-Performance-FullText-Search.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I've read about Sphinx earlier. I'm thinking about instant search on my page and it looks that only way how to deal with my problem and this future idea is the external fulltext engine.